# Blank page between transitions jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When using transitions to navigate between two pages in my jQuery Mobile application, I see a blank page between the two pages. This behavior occurs at least on the Slide transition, fade does not show this behavior.

My page structure is like this:

```
<div id="MainPanelPage" data-role="page">
  <div id="MenuLeft" data-role="panel">
    ...
  </div>
  <div data-role="header">
    ...
  </div>
  <div data-role="ui-content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div id="BannerPage" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    ...
  </div>
  <div data-role="ui-content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note: jQuery Mobile wraps these divs into a global div automatically.**

I am calling the transition with the following link:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl25" value="Meer informatie" onclick="$.mobile.navigate('#BannerPage', { transition: 'slide' });" data-role="button" href="#BannerPage" data-transition="slide">
```

Please note that I am running ASP.NET and the language is kind of dirty in combination with jQuery Mobile.

I am running jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. After spending hours of trying I decided to ask here for a possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also include your jQuery code

Comment: I have added the code of the linkbutton.